# Could not find or load main class src.main.Main

Tags: java, eclipse

I imported a GitHub project onto Eclipse by forking it and then importing it through Eclipse and I keep getting this error... I'm using Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0) of Eclipse and the latest version of Java

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class src.main.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [LString;
```

I was able to get through that by removing the JRE System Library and adding it back, but then I get this error...

```
Error: Could not find or load main class src.main.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: src.main.Main
```

Have already tried re-importing and restarting Eclipse. Never had this issue before and not sure what to do.
Here is the link to the GitHub project
https://github.com/nicomp42/TwoLiterStack

My class is named "main.Main" but it's not running. Just the error

Comment: What version of Java are you using? What version of Java does the project require? Double check. Also, how did you import the project?

Comment: Your class is named "main.Main", not "src.main.Main". How are you running your program?

Comment: Post a screen capture of the _Run Configuration_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by going into the run configurations and where it says main.Main, it used to say src.main.Main. Simply taking out the 'src.' fixed it.

[image]

Comment: I have seen this happen many many times when cloning a repo containing an Eclipse project from GitHub. It's great to see a solution documented.